# How to style css in angular2 from different component so they can well suited each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular2-template

i trying to create a sub component of angular2 css well suited each other? here is my problem, when i create a sub component and then i called my component with the selector, my css that bigger than the other component hidden in side my selector component, here is my project structur :
[image]

then here is my home.html :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="homecarousel-recent-offer col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <carouselItemsme></carouselItemsme>
  </div>
</div>
```

that's how i call my sub component, then here is come my problem
[image]

here is the look of my tooltip html get hidden in side the component, here is my carouselItems.scss :

```
.carousel-recent-offers {
position:relative;
}

.carousel-recent-offers .next-carousel, .carousel-recent-offers .previous-carousel {
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(234,235,236,0.7);
    height: 100%;
    color: #70747c;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

    .next-carousel, .previous-carousel{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        width: 36px;
        line-height: 38px;
        height: 38px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #70747c;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: none;

        z-index: 2;
        border: none;


    }

    .next-carousel {
        right: 0;
    }

    .previous-carousel:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .next-carousel:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .offer--carousel {
        display: inline-block;
        //height: 285px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
        border-radius: 2px;
        position: relative;
    }

    /* Tooltip text */
    .offer--carousel .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: auto;
        background-color: white;
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 6px;

        /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 105%; 
        z-index: 9000;
    }

    .offer--carousel .tooltiptext::after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 100%;
        margin-top: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
    }

    .offer--carousel:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    a img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 140px;
    }

    .offer--carousel .offer__details {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .offer--carousel .offer__title {
        max-height: 40px;
        color: #006cb7;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-overflow: inherit;
        white-space: normal;
    }

    .offer__title, .offer__subtitle {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .offer__subtitle {
        color: #212121;
    }

.rating--carousel
    .rating--carousel .rating__reviews {
        color: #b9bcc2 !important;
    }
    .rating__value, .rating__reviews {
        display: block;
    }
    .rating--carousel .rating__value, .rating--carousel .rating__reviews {
        color: #212121;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .price--mini-dark {
        top: 1px;
        right: 1px;
        padding: 5px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: rgba(2,21,33,0.8);
        position: absolute;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .price--mini-dark .price__tag {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .price--mini-dark .price__info {
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
```

how can i make my tooltip get outside the selector area if the tooltip box is big and have many content in it?

UPDATE :
you guys can just focus on this css code, here is how i use to create a tooltip

```
.offer--carousel {
    display: inline-block;
    //height: 285px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.offer--carousel .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: auto;
    background-color: white;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 105%; 
    z-index: 9000;
}

.offer--carousel .tooltiptext::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
}

.offer--carousel:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

and here is my carouselItems.html

```
<ks-swiper-slide *ngFor="let s of data; let i = index" >
    <a class="offer--carousel" [routerLink]="['/course-detail', s._id]" routerLinkActive="active">
      <div class="offer-image__column">
        <img [src]="s.courseLandingPage.course_image">
      </div>
      <div class="offer-details__column">
        <div class="offer__details">
          <h3 class="offer__title">
            {{s.courseLandingPage.course_title}}
          </h3>
          <div class="offer__subtitle">
            {{s.courseLandingPage.course_subtitle}}
          </div>
          <div class="offer__rating">
            <div class="rating--carousel">
              <span class="rating__value">9.4 Excellent</span>
              <span class="rating__reviews">(44 reviews)</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="price--mini-dark">
          <div class="price__tag">
            {{s.price_coupons.price}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tooltiptext">
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
        <div>ksadjfkljsalfjdsakldfa</div>
      </div>
    </a>
</ks-swiper-slide>
```

Notes : i use ks-swiper-slide for the slider, can be the ks-swiper-slide is the problem?

Comment: Are you using any plugin for tooltip.?

Comment: @JithinRajPR no i simply CSS my tooltip, i update my question for the css code

Comment: I think you may misuse a tooltip which should be a small "hover box" with information about the item being hovered over.

Comment: @Vega i think creating tooltip and hover box is the same since i create it with CSS right? you can see my css and html code, i just updated my question

Comment: @KeVin, the thing is your tooltip is inside `.offer--carousel` and it will not get outside its parent if you use `absolute` as the position you have to use `fixed` for that. In this case, can I suggest a better **jQuery plugin** for this

Comment: @JithinRajPR oh so it's impossible to get it outside its parent? what jQuery plugin did u suggest for?

Comment: I will post as answer ok

Comment: ok @JithinRajPR wait for it xD

Comment: @Ke Vin, I was emphasizing on the 'small' in 'the small hover box'. If it contains a big content it's no more a tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is your tooltip is inside `.offer--carousel` and it will not get outside its **parent** if you use `absolute` and the parent(s) has a style of `overflow: hidden` as the position you have to use `fixed` for that and it will **harder to manage**. In this case, can I suggest a better **jQuery plugin** for this:

I will go with [**Tooltipster**](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) if I were you. It has many customize option as well.Hope this helps you ty.

Comment: i think its better to use angular2 plugin, in some article that i read, they said its better to reduce use for jQuery plugins, since there is a DOM in it, and first thing i dunno how to integrade jQuery plugin into angular2. But your answer have answered my question, i will open up new question for anguar2 tooltip, thank you!

Comment: @KeVin One more thing is there 'is any parent div' with style `overflow: hidden` for the tooltip. I think they are the reason for this hiding elements. So it's better to use the plugin as their value will be dynamical and it will be not affected by any other parent div.